# Why doesn't my program go to next question

Tags: c, for-loop, variables, scanf

I'm attempting to write a small program that a user input book information in the "struct bookinfo" and then print what user write.

I accepted some advice in my past question. so I modified my program but It is still not working
problem is that my program doesn't go to next question. If I put a character in integer variable
It goes to next question but skip next question again!

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

struct bookInfo {
    char title [40];
    char author [25];
    float price;
    int pages;
};

main()
{
    int ctr;
    struct bookInfo books[3];
    for (ctr = 0 ; ctr< 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
        scanf( " %s", books[ctr]. title);
        puts("who is the author?");
        scanf(" %s", books[ctr].author);
        puts("How much did the book cost? ");
        scanf("%f", &books[ctr].price);
        puts("How many pages in the book? ");
        scanf("%d", &books[ctr].pages);
        getchar();
    }
```

output is Here.

```
What is the name of the book #1?
cosmos
who is the author?
kalcaygon
How much did the book cost?
14.99
```

and then, my program doesn't go to next question. but when I put a character, it go to next question. but skip next input like this

```
What is the name of the book #1?
cosmos
who is the author?
kalcaygon
How much did the book cost?
14.99





d
How many pages in the book?
who is the author?
How much did the book cost?
```

Comment: Don't call `getchar`. And don't use the leading space in the `scanf` format strings. Neither are needed with the code you show.

Comment: you miss the `}` at the end of the code for close the `main() {`

Comment: Maybe you have an extra space in your real scanf: `scanf("%f ", &books[ctr].price);` ?? After adding a final `}`, [your code works as is](https://ideone.com/IOsh0f) ... **but turn on and mind your compiler warnings!**

Comment: @pmg you saved my life...! Now I realized my fault thank you so much!!

Comment: @JeonSoomin Your code is working fine in my system.  There is no problem with `scanf( " %s", books[ctr]. title);`  statement. But you will run into problems with `scanf( "%s ", books[ctr]. title);`

Comment: Please check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string

Comment: Why is this question tagged with the **D** programming language?